# How to use a variable within my SELECT (T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I've written a crazy `INSERT/SELECT` statement that works pretty well, except that I think it can be tuned a wee bit more if I can avoid using the `LEN([stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainName])` twice. Right now it takes 20 seconds to run, and if I replace these `LEN` sections with actual numbers for a test, it literally takes a second, hence my hope!

I've been racking my brain on how to get that into a variable so I can use it twice but only have one performance hit.  I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2 for what it is worth.

Thanks much!

```
INSERT INTO [stats].[dbo].[5MinStats] (Qty, MsgRequest, MsgRecType, MsgDateTime, DomainID)
   SELECT
      COUNT([stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgRequest]) AS Qty, 
      [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgRequest], 
      [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgRecType], 
      DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgDateTime])/ 5 * 5, 0) AS MsgDateTime, 
      [stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainID] 
   FROM 
      [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog], [stats].[dbo].[Domain]
   WHERE 
      RIGHT([stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainName], LEN([stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainName])) = RIGHT([stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgRequest], LEN([stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainName]))
      AND [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[switch] = 1
   GROUP BY 
      [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgRequest], 
      [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgRecType], 
      DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgDateTime]) / 5 * 5, 0), 
      [stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainID]
   ORDER BY 
      MsgDateTime ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your `WHERE` to the following:

```
WHERE stats.dbo.Domain.DomainName LIKE '%' + stats.dbo.RawMsgLog.MsgRequest
```

This avoids the `RIGHT()` and `LEN()` functions, and allows your query to use any available indexes... applying functions to your indexed columns will obfuscate them and cause a scan to be used instead.

I would also make a few other changes...

1. Alias your tables.
2. Don't use `[]` if you don't need to...
3. Use explicit `JOIN`.

Which would give you the following query:

```
INSERT INTO stats.dbo.5MinStats (
    Qty, 
    MsgRequest, 
    MsgRecType, 
    MsgDateTime, 
    DomainID
)
SELECT 
    COUNT(rml.MsgRequest) as Qty, 
    rml.MsgRequest, 
    rml.MsgRecType, 
    DATEADD(minute, 
      DATEDIFF(minute, 0, rml.MsgDateTime)/ 5 * 5, 0) as MsgDateTime, 
    d.DomainID 
FROM 
    stats.dbo.RawMsgLog rml
    JOIN stats.dbo.Domain d
        ON d.DomainName LIKE '%' + rml.MsgRequest
WHERE rml.switch=1
GROUP BY 
    rml.MsgRequest, 
    rml.MsgRecType, 
    dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, rml.MsgDateTime)/ 5 * 5, 0), 
    d.DomainID
ORDER BY MsgDateTime ASC
```

Comment: I'm suspicious of the use of `LIKE`, and the side the wildcard is on; the function he's using is `RIGHT`, which means it should be `WHERE stats.dbo.Domain.DomainName LIKE '%' + stats.dbo.RawMsgLog.MsgRequest` - or am I missing something?

Comment: +1 - and much more readable.  Good job!  It still confuses me why people still don't alias, indent, capitalise keywords, etc.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse You're right... the `%` was on the wrong side... the leading wildcard will prevent `MsgRequest` from being SARGable... but I'd still recommend this approach because if there's an index on `DomainName`, it should be usable.

Comment: Oh yeah, at least getting rid of the one `RIGHT()` over the domain name should help.

Comment: Thanks! I actually had like '%' + [stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainName] before and the query took 2 minutes to run where the one above takes about 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CHARINDEX` to speed this up:

```
WHERE CHARINDEX([stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainName], [stats].[dbo].[RawMsgLog].[MsgRequest]) > 0
```

This will return true if the value in `DomainName` is found anywhere in the `MsgRequest` column.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not familiar with CHARINDEX. I gave it a whirl, and it sadly added about 10 seconds : (

Answer (score 0):

In the first half of your condition, you do a "right" with the length of the substring being the same as length of the field itself (i.e. right(field, len(field)).  You can remove this and just use the field itself.  Then, your comparison can be wildcard text:

```
WHERE stats.dbo.RawMsgLog.MsgRequest like '%' + stats.dbo.Domain.DomainName
```

you can also use this substring comparison, but I imagine it would be slower.

```
right(stats.dbo.RawMsgLog.MsgRequest, LEN(stats.dbo.Domain.DomainName)) = stats.dbo.Domain.DomainName
```

Comment: Thanks, I posted above too... I actually had like '%' + [stats].[dbo].[Domain].[DomainName] before and the query took 2 minutes to run where the one above takes about 20 seconds. But I will try the substring for fun. I'm game for anything!

Comment: The substring comparison saves about 2 seconds. Every little bit helps!

Comment: I think the reason it's slow is that the substring is using fields from two different tables.  The database is having to take the length of a field from domain and then applying it to the rawmsglog field.  What sort of indexes do you have on these tables, and have you tried optimizing with that?

Comment: I have great indexes on all tables but the RawMsgLog, which is why it is a killer. I can't index that table because data only resides in it for 10 minutes at the most, then it is completely replaced. Any index would be fragmented within moments : (

Comment: A few other thoughts on your query in general.  You are doing a count on _MsgRequest_ but then have that as part of your group by, therefore wouldn't the count always be 1?  Also, you are only pulling one column from _domain_ (the domainId) but doing a full join.  Maybe try putting this into your select section with something like `(select top 1 d.domainID from stats.dbo.domain d where RawMsgLog.MsgRequest like '%'  + d.domainname) as 'DomainID'`